# Trouble with pointer, that can't explain in title

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

When it award `lineptr[nlines++] = p` , in next lap of loop that do again ,`lineptr[nlines++] = p` , does `lineptr[--nlines]` (element of `lineptr[]` , one element before who `p` pointed to) , will he change because p changed. I try with simple example, with some integers to try realize this , but it gave me different "result"? I found this example, `lineptr[nlines++] = p` , in k&r book.

```
int readlines(char *lineptr[], int maxlines)
{
int len, nlines;
char *p, line[MAXLEN];

nlines = 0;
while ((len = getline(line, MAXLEN)) > 0)
if (nlines >= maxlines || (p = malloc(len)) == NULL)
  return -1;
else {
  line[len - 1] = '\0';  /* delete the newline */
  strcpy(p, line);
  lineptr[nlines++] = p;
                 }                       
return nlines;  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you're asking whether changing the value of `p` to use in the next loop pass modifies the array element that was set to `p`'s value in the previous pass... and the answer would be *no*.  When each array element is assigned:

```
lineptr[nlines++] = p;
```

it becomes a copy of whatever value `p` has *at the time of the assignment*... changing `p` (the pointer value) later doesn't modify the array element.  If you had changed what `p` *points to* without changing `p` itself, things would be different since the array element would still point to the same data.

Comment: Thank for good explanation, but can u explain me this? , why here change value of p?
   ' int *p;
    int b= 13;
    p = &b;
    printf("p is: %d\n", *p);
    b = 32;
    printf("p is: %d\n", *p);'

Comment: @lotoflaugh `p` does not change in that example, but `*p` changes. `p` still points to the same memory, but the memory where `p` points to changes.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you basically ask about the following situation:

```
char *lineptr[];
char *p;
int nlines=0;

// first loop
p = malloc(len);
strcpy(p, line);
lineptr[nlines++] = p;  // will assign lineptr[0]

// second loop
p = malloc(len);
strcpy(p, line);
lineptr[nlines++] = p;  // will assign lineptr[1]
```

The second loop does not change anyting in `lineptr` what was assigned in the first loop.

`p` stores the result of `malloc()`, which is a pointer to some memory. Every call to `malloc` will point to different memory. When you reassign `p`, the previous value is lost, so it cannot change anything any more where it was pointing to before. And `lineptr` will never point to `p`, but it will be a copy of `p` at the moment of assignment.

My example above can also be written as:

```
char *lineptr[];
int nlines=0;

// first loop
lineptr[nlines] = malloc(len);  // will assign lineptr[0]
strcpy(lineptr[nlines], line);  
nlines++;

// second loop
lineptr[nlines] = malloc(len);  // will assign lineptr[1]
strcpy(lineptr[nlines], line);
nlines++;
```

Let me know if it is not clear yet.